# How do I set a default time to my timepicker?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, timepicker

I have I time picker in my code and when I press the edit text it shows up and everything looks good but I want to set a default time for my time picker so when the user opens the time picker it will be shown a specific time like "3:34 am" as a default time for the user, how can I do that?. Any help will be appreciated. { you can use java and kotlin}

**My time picker**

```
private fun showTimePicker() {
    picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(0)
            .setTitleText("حدد الموعد الذي تريدة")
            .build()

    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "AdhanNotifacations")
    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        if (picker.hour > 12) {
            fajrEditTxt.setHint(String.format("%02d", picker.hour - 12) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", picker.minute) + " PM")
        } else {
            fajrEditTxt.setHint(String.format("%02d", picker.hour) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", picker.minute) + " AM")
        }
        calender = Calendar.getInstance()
        calender[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour
        calender[Calendar.MINUTE] = picker.minute
        calender[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        calender[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, just **change the value** of `setHour` and `setMinute` to the hour and minute you want respectively.

I made few changes to your code to show default time of **3:34am**:

```
picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
    .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
    .setHour(3) //3 hour
    .setMinute(34) //34 minutes, so 3:34am
    .setTitleText("حدد الموعد الذي تريدة")
    .build()
```

If you want to show hour in **PM**, just **add 12** to the hour. For example:

```
setHour(15)// will show 3pm
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

### EDIT

If you want to show time in **strict** `HH:MM` format you can keep your code and **go as-is**. But if you **do not** wish to be strict, then use the following code:

For example, this will show `9:3PM` instead of `09:03PM`.

```
//removed unnecesarry String.format
if(picker.hour > 12){
    fajrEditTxt.setHint((picker.hour - 12).toString() + ":" + (picker.minute).toString() + " PM")
}else{
    fajrEditTxt.setHint((picker.hour).toString() + ":" + (picker.minute).toString() + " AM")
}
```

**OP** asked how to access time:

```
val time = if(picker.hour > 12){
    String.format("%02d",picker.hour - 12) + ":" + String.format("%02d", picker.minute) + " PM"
}else{
    String.format("%02d",picker.hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", picker.minute) + " AM"
}
time //use time, its in HH:MM format
fajrEditTxt.setHint(time)
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to parse a time that has the hour and the minutes combined like "hh:mm" because I have a library and it gives me the time like "hh:mm".. thank u

Comment: sure but I am confused with your question, do you want to format time to "hh:mm"? or something else?

Comment: @Abood I have made updates to myself. Please check and see if it answers your additional question. Thanks.

Comment: the hour and the minutes on your answer was not combined. I need the hour and the minutes to be combined like "hh:mm" so I can retrieve the time from the library if that's possible

Comment: They are combined... are you saying that you want to remove AM and PM from time?  "09:30AM" to "09:30" ?

Comment: @Abood I have added a new variable `time` so that you can access it later. I think this was what you meant... See my updated answer.. Thanks.

Comment: thank you.. your answer seems good.. I will check it as soon as I turn on my computer.

Comment: Sure. I am glad to help. Feel free to ask more questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you .. It solved the question's issue

Comment: @Abood I am glad I could be of help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding what it is you're asking, but if you're trying to sort the times in the library, you could place the times in a list and then sort the list, or if you just want to compare the magnitude values of two different times with just a couple of lines of code, you could remove the time separators from the time strings, convert those values to numbers ( of your choice ) and compare. The numbers generated from the conversions have no real world values, but their magnitudes with respect to one another will always be valid.

Oh. Snippet editor does not support touch devices.

Ok then.

```
String time = "00:00";

  time.replace( ":", "" );

  Double d = Double.parseDouble( time );
```

So now you can do with d as you wish. As you can see you don't have to bother with whether any of the values are to great. If you're dealing with a pair of valid times it's their relative magnitudes that matters. Of course if the time is in 12 Hr format, you'll need to strip the time modifier ( A, a, P, p, Am, AM .... ) too.